# Compare Collection of Collections

Tags: c#, list, compare

I have a class called Folder which looks like

```
public class Folder
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Titel{get;set;}
  public List<Folder> Folders{get;set;}
  public List<Document> Documents{get;set;}
}
```

I get a list of Folders from a database every 10 seconds. Now I need to compare the new list of folders with the one I've got already in memory.

What is the best way to do this?

My first approach was to do:

```
if(currentFolders.GetHashCode() != newFolders.GetHashCode())
{
  // Work with changed data
}
```

Also if both collections are identical I get different hashcodes.

My second try was to mark the class as `[Serializable]` and serialize both lists into `Byte[]`

```
byte[] b1, b2;

    using (var m1 = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var m2 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(m1, newFolders);
            b1 = m1.ToArray();

            binaryFormatter.Serialize(m2, currentFolders);
            b2 = m2.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately the `Folder`-`class` is automatically generated through Linq2SQL, so I can't easily mark it as `Serializable`

What else can I do to compare these two collections?

Comment: Implement `IEquatable<T>` or create `IEqualityComparer<T>` where `T` is `Folder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself with:

```
internal class FolderComparer
{
    internal bool AreCollectionsEqual(IEnumerable<Folder> folderList1, IEnumerable<Folder> folderList2)
    {
        var flatFolderList1 = BuildFlatFolderList(folderList1);
        var flatFolderList2 = BuildFlatFolderList(folderList2);
        return !flatFolderList1.Except(flatFolderList2).Any();
    }


    private IEnumerable<int> BuildFlatFolderList(IEnumerable<Folder> folders)
    {
        List<int> folderIdList = new List<int>();
        DoBuildFlatFolderList(folders, folderIdList);
        return folderIdList;
    }

    private void DoBuildFlatFolderList(IEnumerable<Folder> folders, ICollection<int> resultList)
    {
        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            resultList.Add(folder.Id);
            DoBuildFlatFolderList(folder.Folders.ToList(), resultList);
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided:

- your Document class has a single Name property
- your collections don't contain null instances
- your comparison should return true in case of equality and false otherwise

You can do the following:

```
public bool Compare(Document expected, Document actual)
{
  return (actual.Name == expected.Name);
}

public bool Compare(Folder expected, Folder actual)
{
  return (actual.Id == expected.Id) &&
         (actual.Titel == expected.Titel) &&
         Compare(actual.Documents, expected.Documents, Compare) &&
         Compare(actual.Folders, expected.Folders, Compare);
}

public bool Compare<T>(ICollection<T> expected, ICollection<T> actual, 
                       Func<T, T, bool> comparer)
{
  return (actual.Count == expected.Count) &&
          actual.Zip(expected, (left, right) => comparer(left, right)).
          All(comparison => comparison);
}
```

which can be used the following way:

```
List<Folder> previous = ...
List<Folder> current = /* Get from DB */
if (!Compare(previous, current))
{
  // Something changed
}
```

You can also implement [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) implementations

Comment: I didn't get your solution to work, but I've already solved it by myself